# How to use the known weights of different breaking points in German words?

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation, german

In https://repo.or.cz/wortliste.git/blob/HEAD:/wortliste (which is, in my opinion, the source of the current German hyphenation patterns used by [PDF|Xe|Lua]LaTeX with `\babelprovide[hyphenrules=ngerman-x-latest]{ngerman}`) we see that for many words the priorities of the breaking points are specified.  For example, for *Fußgängerampel* the breaking-point choices are specified as `Fuß=gän-ger==am-pel`. If I get it right, this means that

- *Fußgängerampel* is a compound word, being composed of *Fußgänger* and *ampel*, and can be split between the two parts;
- *Fußgänger* is itself a compound word, being composed of *Fuß* and *gänger*, and can be split between the two parts;
- *gänger* can be split at the syllable border as *gän-ger*, and the breaking point is within a morpheme, and, similarly,
- *ampel* can be split at the syllable border as *am-pel*, and the breaking point is within a morpheme.

Moreover, `Fuß=gän-ger==am-pel` tells us that the main way to split the word is *Fußgänger-ampel*, doesn't it?

Any way to tell [Xe|Lua|PDF]LaTeX to use this information?  As of TeX Live from today, on 2022-08-23, feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=ngerman-x-latest]{ngerman}% provides me with patterns from 2022-03-16 as of now
% \hyphenpenalty=49%% one less than the default value 50.
% \exceptionpenalty=50%% ad-hoc value greater than \hyphenpenalty.
% \exhyphenpenalty=48%% ad-hoc value less than \hyphenpenalty (though usually they coincide).
% \babelhyphenation[ngerman]{Fuß{-}{}{}[1]gän{-}{}{}[2]ger-am{-}{}{}[2]pel}%% of course, we could have an exception list.
\showoutput
\begin{document}
Fußgängerampel
\end{document}
```

to `lualatex` yields

```
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 F
....\kern-0.83 (font)
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 u
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 ß
....\discretionary (penalty 50)
.....< \TU/lmr/m/n/10 -
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 g
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 ä
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 n
....\discretionary (penalty 50)
.....< \TU/lmr/m/n/10 -
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 g
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 e
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 r
....\discretionary (penalty 50)
.....< \TU/lmr/m/n/10 -
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 a
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 m
....\discretionary (penalty 50)
.....< \TU/lmr/m/n/10 -
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 p
....\kern0.28 (font)
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 e
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 l
```

on the standard output.
This means, unfortunately, that LuaLaTeX does not prefer any of the four breaking points over any other one, does it?

Answer (score 2):

Look at Keno Wehr's [autotype](https://codeberg.org/wehr/autotype/) package for LuaLaTeX, which provides weighted hyphenation for German, together with automatic prevention of wrong ligatures at compound word boundaries (for example, 'Auf-lage') and automatic replacement of round s with long s ( ſ ) for typesetting with Fraktur fonts.

The biggest drawback of using this package is currently that processing documents becomes *much* slower.